# Layer cannot be found

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#

```c#
public Int32 GetIndexNumberFromLayerName(String layerName)

        {
            IMxDocument doc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
            IActiveView activeView = doc.ActiveView;

            if (activeView == null || layerName == null)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            IMap map = activeView.FocusMap;

            // Get the number of layers
            int numberOfLayers = map.LayerCount; //returns zero to me

            // Loop through the layers and get the correct layer index
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < numberOfLayers; i++)
            {
                if (layerName == map.get_Layer(i).Name)
                {
                    // Layer was found
                    return i;
                }
            }

            // No layer was found
            return -1;
        }
```

Why my code doesn't work? Number of layers is 6. Layer name is valid. ArcMap 10 and C#

Comment: maybe IMap map = doc.FocusMap will do?

Comment: Nope, it won't. My further idea is to insert layer attribute into ComboBox, but I have this problem.

Comment: Did you try vinayan's suggestion? I always define iMap object with iMxDocument (not iActiveView)

Comment: lcoursey, yes I did, and it has not worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference **My.ArcMap.Application.Document**.  Code snippet is in VB, but will produce the map layer count.

```
Dim mxdoc As IMxDocument
Dim pMap As IMap

mxdoc = CType(My.ArcMap.Application.Document, IMxDocument)

pMap = mxdoc.ActiveView.FocusMap
Dim layerCount As Integer = pMap.LayerCount
MessageBox.Show("Layer Count = " & layerCount.ToString)
```

Comment: How should I use IApplication? In your snippet it casts to hook and does no more.

Comment: @James Tomatov, Just a fragment statement from old code, it is not needed.  See my edited answer.

Comment: In the myTool this code is valid. But in the my docPanel this code doesn't contain valid data in xDoc and Map interfaces.